# Client not Responding from more than last 36 Hours

Tags: payments, communication, programmer, project

I recently got my first project on Up Work, i had a lot of communication with two of the people from their side on Skype and i have been working on their project from previous week, i have developed couple of User Interfaces for that application, all was going good, but suddenly when yesterday morning time i asked him to schedule a voice call on Skype in night to discuss some things related to project, he didn't replied, and now it is more than 36 hours being passed and both of them are not replying to my messages in the group at Skype and neither in private messages, their status keeps showing offline.

I am confused what is going on, what should i do now, should i continue working on the project, or wait for them to response back, because i am afraid they might don't want to continue on this project.

and another thing to note is that my first week payment status is also in review right now.

Comment: 36 hours is not a lot of time. It's entirely possible the client has been busy and offline for a day and a half or two. I have some clients that take a week to respond to me.

Comment: Relax, I've been on the client side on upwork as well and there have been times when I simply couldn't respond (or didnt want to) within that time frame. Give 'em a day or two!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless the client made assurances to be immediately contactable during this period, they have no urgent need to respond. There are anumber of things that might be diverting their attention.

I would suggest allowing at least 72 hours before following up.